# django forms give: Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, django-forms

I am unable to catch the values from the `unit_id` after the selection is done by the user and data is posted. Can someone help me to solve this.

The values of the `unit_id` drop down list is obtained from another database table (`LiveDataFeed`). And once a value is selected and form posted, it gives the error:

***Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.***

Here is the implementation:

**in models.py:**

```
class CommandData(models.Model):
    unit_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    command = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    communication_via = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=COMMAND_STATUS)
```

**In views.py:**

```
class CommandSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    iquery = LiveDataFeed.objects.values_list('unit_id', flat=True).distinct()
    unit_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=iquery, empty_label='None',
        required=False, widget=forms.Select())

class Meta:
    model = CommandData
    fields = ('unit_id', 'command', 'communication_via')

def CommandSubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommandSubmitForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponsRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = CommandSubmitForm()

    return render_to_response('command_send.html', {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Does changing `.distinct` to `.distinct()` help?

Comment: That was a typo above... it is already coded as .distinct()...

Answer (score 19):

You're getting a flat value_list back which will just be a list of the ids, but when you do that, you're probably better off using a plain `ChoiceField` instead of a `ModelChoiceField` and providing it with a list of tuples, not just ids. For example:

```
class CommandSubmitForm(ModelForm):
    iquery = LiveDataFeed.objects.values_list('unit_id', flat=True).distinct()
    iquery_choices = [('', 'None')] + [(id, id) for id in iquery]
    unit_id = forms.ChoiceField(iquery_choices,
                                required=False, widget=forms.Select())
```

You could also leave it as a `ModelChoiceField`, and use `LiveDataFeed.objects.all()` as the queryset, but in order to display the id in the  box as well as have it populate for the option values, you'd have to subclass `ModelChoiceField` to override the `label_from_instance` method. You can see an [example in the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Comment: Thanks Dan. This is my implementation.{{  iquery = LiveDataFeed.objects.values_list("unit_id",flat=True).distinct()
        iquery_choices = [('', 'None')] + [(str(id), str(id)) for id in iquery]
        print "Choices are :", iquery_choices
        unit_id = forms.ChoiceField(choices=iquery_choices)}}

Answer (score 8):

Before you call `form.is_valid()`, do the following:

1. `unit_id = request.POST.get('unit_id')`
2. `form.fields['unit_id'].choices = [(unit_id, unit_id)]`

Now you can call `form.is_valid()` and your form will validate correctly.

Comment: Could you explain it with the example of `queryset` instead of `choices`. Your method is useful when there are multiple `ajax` calls and I want to use it just before the validation. But it is not working for me.

Comment: What's bad about this is if user submits any value for unit_id, even one that isn't in the database, the validation will work. Meanwhile the value is NOT in the database.

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but i faced the same problem, the solution according the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is to add to_field_name="name" where name is the column you want to show on the choices

```
iquery = LiveDataFeed.objects.values_list('unit_id', flat=True).distinct()
unit_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=iquery, empty_label='None',
    required=False, widget=forms.Select(),to_field_name="unit_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the _*init* function. Use *Limited_condition* variable that delete this field in update view. in my case 'author' field caused problem 'Select a valid choice'. I just removed it in initiation of the form.

```
forms.py
    class UrlentryForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Urlentry
    fields = ['url_text', 'author', 'url_id', 'datetime_available_from', 'datetime_available_to', 'partner_ads','qr_code','snapshot']
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    limited_condition = kwargs.pop('limited_condition', None)
    super(UrlentryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if limited_condition:
        del self.fields['author']
        self.fields['url_id'].widget = HiddenInput()
        self.fields['url_id'].required = False
        self.fields['qr_code'].widget = HiddenInput()
        self.fields['qr_code'].required = False
        self.fields['snapshot'].widget = HiddenInput()
        self.fields['snapshot'].required = False
```

Then modify views.py

```
views.py
    @login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('auth:login'))
    def update_urlentry(request, pk):
        #....
    if request.method == "POST":
            urlentry_form = UrlentryForm(request.POST, instance=urlentry, limited_condition=True)
            if urlentry_form.is_valid():
                urlentry = urlentry_form.save(commit=False)
                # additional modification of urlentry, if needed
                urlentry.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request, urlentry_form.errors)
    redirect('polls:detail', pk=urlentry.pk)
```

#and finalizing code follows here

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is populating the choices to the form before calling the `is_valid()` method.

```
form = CommandSubmitForm(request.POST)
form.fields["unit_id"].choices = choices
if form.is_valid():
  # add your logic here
```