# Django ModelForms return from selectfield

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, django-forms

I'm having trouble building a dropdown (with active search filtering) that displays an attribute (name) of all the objects present in a model (Courses). I found [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) to be a nice opton to implment this and hence installed [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2).

This is what I have so far, content omitted for brevity.

**models.py**

```python
class Course(models.Model):
    courseID = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank="True", null="True")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank="True", null="True")
    hasProject = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    taughtBy = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

**urls.py**

```python
url(r'^courses/$', courses)
```

**forms.py**

```python
from django import forms
import django_select2
from django_select2 import *
from models import Course

class CourseForm(forms.Form):  # also tried forms.ModelForm -> same results
    Title = ModelSelect2Field(widget=django_select2.Select2Widget(select2_options={
        'width': '400px',
        'placeholder': '',
    })
        , queryset=Course.objects.values_list('name', flat=True))
```

**views.py**

```python
def courses(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CourseForm()
        print "Form Type:", type(form)
        print "ERRORS:", form.errors
        if form.is_valid():
            course = form.cleaned_data['Title']
            print "Course Selected:", course
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
        form = CourseForm()
        return render(request, 'templates/home/courses.html', {'form': form})
```

**courses.html**

```python
<form method="POST" id="courseForm" action="#" style="padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="badge pull-right">Hint: You can start typing the title of the course</div>
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form }}
        </table>
        <div style="padding-left: 380px; padding-top: 10px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

**The Problem**

The form is always invalidated and the errors are blank. Form type is `Type: <class 'coursereview.forms.CourseForm'>`.

I'm displaying the dropdown as a `ModelForm` but the flat list contains the *name* of the objects and hence I get `Type: <class 'coursereview.forms.CourseForm'>` instead of a ModelForm - so I can't decode what was the course selected and display the corresponding page accordingly.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536107/django-forms-give-select-a-valid-choice-that-choice-is-not-one-of-the-availabl) and was thinking of overriding the `label_from_instance`. I'm having trouble with it as I'm using `django-select2`. I tried making it a `ChoiceField`, but the form was still invalidated with errors. Besides, the dropdown looked uglier than that of select2. :P

```python
class CourseForm(ModelForm):
    iquery = Course.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
    iquery_choices = [('', 'None')] + [(id, id) for id in iquery]
    Title = forms.ChoiceField(iquery_choices,
                                required=False, widget=forms.Select())
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        exclude = ('taughtBy', 'courseID', 'name', 'hasProject')
```

**Ideally, I would like to use `ModelSelect2Field` that I used in the forms.py mentioned earlier and have the selected course returned from it.**

Comment: You have to use the model form.. I haven't tried this library, but django-selectables worked just fine (you can have a look here https://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with what select field you're using. You're simply not passing the POST data to the form.

You also have some indentation errors in the rest of the view. The whole thing should be:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CourseForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        course = form.cleaned_data['Title']
        print "Course Selected:", course
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
else:
    form = CourseForm()
return render(request, 'templates/home/courses.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Tried it, now I get this from the print statements.
Form Type: <class 'coursereview.forms.CourseForm'>
ERRORS: <ul class="errorlist"><li>Title<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: No matter which option I select - it shows the same error, on the html page too.

Comment: I tried the same with ChoiceField form as mentioned in the question. It actually returned the correct course selected. The search doesn't work if I start typing a subset of the course name (it works in select2)